# how to change how a folder is presented in the browser?

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome

When you drag a folder into chrome (Im sure its pretty much the same in other browsers to), is it then possible to change how the contents of that folder is presented with css/html/javascript or other ways?
Ive read a bit about the html5 file API but im not sure if that applies to this?

Just thought it would be cool if you could, never seen anything written on the subject thou

Comment: You want to change how Chrome renders `file://` directories. You might be able to do it with a Chrome extension. But don't ask me how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change how `file://` directories render in the browser using Chrome extensions.  By using [content scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html), you can inject CSS and JavaScript into any page, including `file://` pages.  Put a simple `manifest.json` file in a new directory:

```
{
    "name": "Style My Directories",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["file:///*"],
        "css":["my_styles.css"]
      }
    ]
}
```

Also put your CSS file, named `my_styles.css`, in the same directory as `manifest.json`.

Finally, go to `chrome://extensions`, enable "Developer Mode", and import your new extension directory with the "Load unpacked extension..." button.

Answer (score 0):

Most websites running in browsers that are HTML5 kings, use Flash support for Drag Drop file/folder upload (also implies to the file drag drop in Gmail while composing message)

Install an extension like [**FlashBlock** (Chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cdngiadmnkhgemkimkhiilgffbjijcie) to check this

If flash not found, or you are simply dragging a folder on a blank tab, then depends on the browser what it wants to show you

As of now, you get a file & directory listing in Chrome :)